# How to save taken pictures to a specific folder?

Tags: android, file, camera, directory, photo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get camera result as a uri in data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042695/how-to-get-camera-result-as-a-uri-in-data-folder)

I'm taking a Picure, and saving it in the default folder.

Here is my `PictureCallBack()` function:

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {       

          Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

          OutputStream imageFileOS;

          try {

           imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
           imageFileOS.write(arg0);
           imageFileOS.flush();
           imageFileOS.close();

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image saved: " + uriTarget.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
          }

          camera.startPreview();
         }
    };
```

How can I save it in a specific folder like `"/sdcard/MyCustonApp/Photos/"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your code

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myNewFolder = new File(path + "/your/folder");
    myNewFolder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(path + "/your/folder", name    + ".png");
    OutputStream imageFileOS = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: Nice, but now the picture doesn't show in the gallery or take too long to show. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: To show picture in gallery you must add file with image to gallery:  MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),
     file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

Comment: How did you solve it ? may ypu copy all your code here !?!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I check if the folder I want to save the captured image to, exists, or create the folder if it doesn't.

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyCustomApp/Photos");
else
    cameraFolder = StatusUpdate.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyCustomApp/Photos/camera_snap.jpg");
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, 1);
```

This piece of code will save the captured image to the specified folder with the name **camera_snap** and extension: **.jpg**

NOTE: This requires you to declare the following permission in your `Manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I'm not using intent, I'm making a custom camera app. But the way you check if the folder existir is useful. Thank you!

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida: Oh. My bad. Glad that some of it was useful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
```

Have a look at this link. [How to save images from Camera in Android to specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266572/how-to-save-images-from-camera-in-android-to-specific-folder).

Comment: Thank you, is exactly this, but someone else answered before!

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code and store images in one folder:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/req_images");
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
file = new File(myDir, fname);
Log.i(TAG, "" + file);
if (file.exists())
file.delete();
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where bm means bitmap image name