# How to create a file using content?

Tags: android

After capturing a photo I'm receiving an `Intent data` from which I'm retrieving an `Uri`:

```
Uri contentURI = data.getData();
```

content Uri is `content://media/external/images/media/5576`

Using this `contentURI` I need to save a File to SD card, please advice how. Thank you very much for assistance.

Comment: What comes back from that address, txt,jpg.. ?

Comment: I think, as long as this got from Camera, it should be jpg. content://media/external/images/media/5576

Comment: Looks like this link discusses it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266572/how-to-save-images-from-camera-in-android-to-specific-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not save the Photo to a folder while you are taking a picture from the Camera using an `Intent`? That will speed things up a bit. Try this piece of code for example:

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"CHANGE_TO_YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/camera");
else
    cameraFolder= StatusUpdate.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "CHANGE_TO_YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/camera/camera_snap.jpg");
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
Uri initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, 2);
```