# AIR / Android, content-URI to AS3-file-path

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, filepath

I registered some file-extensions for my AIR-Android-App, so when a file is selected, my app receives an  Invoke-Event in Flash/AS3 with the path to that file.This works fine for files/downloads/links.

However, some Applications provide a a content-uri instead of a direct file-path (e.g. eMail-attachments before they are downloaded).

e.g:
content://gmail-ls/houseatreides@gmail.com/messages/6/attachments/0.1/BEST/false

QUESTION:
How can i turn this into something i can load in AIR/AS3. 
Or how can i order the other application to catch the file for ?
If its not possible in AIR, does anyone know of an ANE that gets the job done ?

I found a post how to do it native in JAVA:

[How to create a file using content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727007/how-to-create-a-file-using-content)

Confirmation that is not possible in AIR is also welcome.
Thank you.

verdave