# saving pictures taken by camera in android app

Tags: java, android, storage, android-camera

I have been stuck on this for a while now and have looked at various tutorials for help but have not yet succeeded.

I have essentially utilised the `camera` function in my **app** to take **pictures** and display a `preview` of it **BUT** it can't save taken picture.

Here is the `java` code containing my attempt to get it functioning according to tutorials:

```
public class Activity_Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton ib;
    ImageView iv;
    Intent i;
    public static final int cameraData = 0;
    Bitmap bmp;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Info:

            Intent i = new Intent(this, Help.class);
            startActivity(i);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        initialise();
    }

    private void initialise() {
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPicReturn);
        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);

        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ibTakePic:
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
           // User cancelled the image capture
       } else {
           // Image capture failed, advise user
       }
    }

    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == cameraData){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_" + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

I have already included all the neccessary `permissions` within the `Manifest.xml` file.

Comment: You pasted a link to Java code, not xml. What is the logcat output? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();   
File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
```

Have a look at this link.[How to save images from Camera in Android to specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266572/how-to-save-images-from-camera-in-android-to-specific-folder)

Answer (score 0):

In your `onClick` where you call the Intent you should specify the output file by utilizing your existing `getOutputMediaFileUri` like this:

```
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputMediaFileUri());
    startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
```

So now YOU are telling the camera where to save the file rather than asking where it was saved.
This is how I got my camera app to work so that I could access the picture after it was snapped.