# Taking photo and saving to internal storage and getting error for getUriForFile

Tags: android, android-camera, android-fileprovider, android-storage

So I'm working on an app where I'm taking a photo and trying to save it to the apps internal storage. I'm having issues with the fileprovider. I have looked at many many of the questions asked on stack overflow, but would like to get a more in detail explanation if possible.

I also followed googles example and it gives me the following error. https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

```
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.debug/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180427_095752_2090822261.jpg
```

Here is the code i have whenever i follow Google's example.

```
<provider
        android:name=".application.blinkupregistration.postworkphotos.PostWorkPhotosFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

In my code.

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile);
```

For the two above, I also tried to hardcode com.myapp.provider into the authorities and getUriForFile method. Also did getpackageName() for the getUriForFile method. But these did not change much. I think the main issue is the paths.

Tried the following paths by using Google's example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="post_work_photos" path="Android/data/${applicationId}/files/Pictures" />
</paths>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="post_work_photos" path="Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

I get this to work whenever I change my paths.xml to the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="post_work_photos" path="." />
</paths>
```

But I do not understand why it works with the period. I also do not know if this the correct practice, which is my main concern.

If anyone can help me out, then that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Don't the path Android starts with a forward slash? ```/Android/```

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Tried it to make sure but this isn't the issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214321/saving-pictures-taken-by-camera-in-android-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214321/saving-pictures-taken-by-camera-in-android-app)

Comment: @Hamdroid that is saving it to the public directory. I'm wanting to save it to the apps storage.

Comment: @huey77 Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> Tried the following paths by using Google's example,

Their example... has issues.

> But I do not understand why it works with the period.

Because you are saying that you are willing to support anything inside of the root of external storage.

> I also do not know if this the correct practice

You could reduce the scope a bit by using `<external-files-path>`:

```
<external-files-path name="post_work_photos" path="." />
```

Now, you are only serving files out of `getExternalFilesDir()`, which is where your file points to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But for some reason I'm not following what you mean by - "Because you are saying that you are willing to support anything inside of the root of external storage." Sorry, probably just having a slow morning.

Comment: @huey77: `<external-path>` maps to the root of *all* of external storage (i.e., everything inside of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. `<external-files-path>` only maps to a particular directory on external storage that is tied to your app.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense. Thanks so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to save a picture to your app's data folder, this should work:

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File image = new File(getApplicationContext().dataDir, "image.jpg");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
```

[context.dataDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#dataDir) is supported since API level 4.

> Full path to the default directory assigned to the package for its persistent data.

Otherwise, if you are working above above API level 24, you can call [`getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) anywhere in context. (Activity, Service, ...)

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.