# Android: Camera opens but doesn't save the taken shot, why?

Tags: android

I am trying to take a picture and save it in the Gallary app. So far I managed to write the following piece of code:

```
public void sendMessages(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessagingAdapter.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
    }


    public Uri getImageUri() {
        picNo++;

        String storageFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CameraImages/";
        String fullFileName = storageFolderPath + picNo + ".jpg";
        File newPic = new File(fullFileName);

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newPic);
        return outputFileUri;
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == 1)
            return;
        if (requestCode == 3) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();  //YOU GET DATA HERE
        }
    }
```

It is working and there is no error. However, it doesn't function as I want.

I am testing on Nexus-7 (CynongeMode) . My app opens the camera alright. But after taking the shot, it freezes on the taken image and gives 3 options (the camera app is a built-in app):

1. Cancel and return from the camera to my app, or
2. Retake the shot, or
3. Accept the taken image !

Now, the first two options work but the 3rd option doesn't do anything AT ALL, it just freezes as shown bellow:

[image]

What might be the problem and why I canoot save the image ?!

---

**UPDATE**

I put a very simple `onActivityResult` method. But it doesn't even go there (when debugging). However, when I remove the `cameraIntent.putExtra` line, then it goes to the `onActivityResult` but again no saved image !!.

Comment: where is the saving code portion?

Comment: Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995185/android-taking-photos-and-saving-them-with-a-custom-name-to-a-custom-destinati) which may help you.

Comment: post your onActivityResult method

Comment: @ShahrairNazimReal : the "takePicture" method is where pictures are taken and saved, isn't it ?!

Comment: @Suda.nese looks like you didn't use the onActivityResult() method?

Comment: post your all related code you missed the `onActivityResult` method?

Comment: @Suda.nese yes it is :) .May be you have missing something in `onActivityResult` method.lets add `onActivityResult`

Comment: @Raghavendra : You are right ! I don't have a `onActivityResult` method. may you please help me with a sample code for saving the image. question: what is the difference between `startActivityForResult` and `oActivityResult` ?!

Comment: @Suda.nese try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010739/android-save-images-in-an-specific-folder

Comment: @R.k.Kushwaha : Thanks for the link, but my code already opens the camera and takes the shot but I am missing the saving part !!

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the permissions into the `Manifest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```